# Delphi: EoleSysError Exception

Tags: user-interface, delphi, exception

I get an EoleSysError exception after executing this line of code:

```
FContainer.DoVerb(ovShow);
```

When I open several word documents in the form, the exception doesn't occur.
Here is an picture of the exception.
For some reason, the error occurs when I want to open an excel file in the form

[image: EoleSysError exception]

This is my current code:

```
procedure TForm1.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
var
  FDocument, FWord:Variant;
  FContainer: TOleContainer;
begin
  FContainer := TOleContainer.Create(olecontainer1);
  FContainer.Modified := false;
  FContainer.Parent := olecontainer1;
  FContainer.Align := alClient;
  FContainer.CreateObject('Word.Document', true);
  FDocument := IDispatch(FContainer.OleObject);
  FWord := FDocument.Application;
  FContainer.DoVerb(ovShow);

  // olecontainer2
  FContainer := TOleContainer.Create(olecontainer2);
  FContainer.Modified := false;
  FContainer.Parent := olecontainer2;
  FContainer.Align := alClient;
  FContainer.CreateObject('Excel.Application', true);
  FDocument := IDispatch(FContainer.OleObject);
  FWord := FDocument.Application;
  FContainer.DoVerb(ovShow);

  FContainer := TOleContainer.Create(olecontainer3);
  FContainer.Modified := false;
  FContainer.Parent := olecontainer3;
  FContainer.Align := alClient;
  FContainer.CreateObject('Word.Document', true);
  FDocument := IDispatch(FContainer.OleObject);
  FWord := FDocument.Application;
  FContainer.DoVerb(ovShow);

  FContainer := TOleContainer.Create(olecontainer4);
  FContainer.Modified := false;
  FContainer.Parent := olecontainer4;
  FContainer.Align := alClient;
  FContainer.CreateObject('Excel.Application', true);
  FDocument := IDispatch(FContainer.OleObject);
  FWord := FDocument.Application;
  FContainer.DoVerb(ovShow);


end;
```

Comment: You haven't opened an excel document just the application. Additional steps to open  / create a workbook or sheet.  Or just create a sheet `FContainer.CreateObject('Excel.Sheet', true);`  For others the error message is "No such interface supported".

Comment: Don't post an image of the error. Instead, hit Ctrl+C with that dialog open, which copies a textual version of the exception into the clipboard. You can then paste that text directly into your post. That makes it searchable by future readers. You should also translate all error messages into English, as this is an English language site. With the image version, I can't even copy/paste the error message myself to use in Google Translate to find out exactly what it says.